# Sort data by timestamp in firebase realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have stored the data in firebase realtime db like below:

```
{
  "orders" : [ null, {
    "res_name" : "order test",
    "res_phone" : "1234567890",
    "timestamp" : 1585123988381
  }, {
    "res_name" : "tesst restaurant",
    "res_phone" : "987654321",
    "timestamp" : 1585124001850
  }, {
    "res_name" : "ppp",
    "res_phone" : "9856847758",
    "timestamp" : 1585124624718
  } ]
}
```

Now I want to sort the data by timestamp value in descending order. How can it be done?

I am doing below to sort the data but it is not working.

```
firebase.database().ref('orders').orderByChild('timestamp').on('value', function(snapshot) {
    var value = snapshot.val();
    var htmls = [];
    $.each(value, function(index, value){

      if(value){

         htmls.push('<tr><td>'+ value.res_name +'</td><td>'+ value.res_phone +'</td><td>'+ value.timestamp +'</td></tr>')
      lastIndex = index;
    });
    $('#tblId').html(htmls);
```

Comment: The code you've posted so far looks fine. What's the problem with it? Hint: the problem is likely in how you handle the data in the `snapshot`, so you'll want to post that code. The simplest way to show the problem is to keep your processing the same, but then `console.log` the problem, instead of building/updating a UI.

Comment: Updated my question...Is it ok now? @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 1):

When you use `orderByChild('timestamp')` on a query, Firebase returns the child nodes that you requested in the order that you requested them. It has three pieces of information for each child node:

- Its key.
- Its value.
- Its order relatively to the other child nodes.

But when you then call `snapshot.val()` it has to convert that information to a JSON, which only has place for the keys and value. So at that point information about the order is dropped.

To process the children in the order you requested them, use `snapshot.forEach()`:

```
firebase.database().ref('orders').orderByChild('timestamp').on('value', function(snapshot) {
    var value = snapshot.val();
    var htmls = [];
    snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
        let value = child.val();
        htmls.push('<tr><td>'+ value.res_name +'</td><td>'+ value.res_phone +'</td><td>'+ value.timestamp +'</td></tr>')
    });
    $('#tblId').html(htmls);
});
```